# Routing WebView2 REST calls to local .NET 5 Controllers

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webview2

I'm currently designing an Angular SPA web client, backed with .NET5 REST.  It's all in the same Visual Studio project, and it builds / runs fine.

I'm now investigating the possibility of distributing this as a windows desktop application.  I was able to get [Electron.NET](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET) to work, but it seems like a round-about solution (Node?!).  I also didn't particularly like that the resources were visible/changeable in the distributed app.

This led me to investigate using WebView2 within WPF (Microsoft seems to be making a similar transition with MSTeams.)  I've found some examples,  but they only use:

1. solely remote content ("www.bing.com")
2. [local content, but only img / html / etc](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jan/14/Taking-the-new-Chromium-WebView2-Control-for-a-Spin-in-NET-Part-1)
3. postmessage, etc to communicate using custom objects.

None of these is what I want.  Well, that's not entirely true. I need #2 to load the Angular SPA, but **when the WebView2-hosted Angular invokes HttpClient, I'd like to intercept that request in the host application and Route it to my REST Controllers**.  This would allow me to keep nearly all of my code intact, and presumably ship a smaller, more obfuscated exe.

Is this possible?  obvious?  Is my desire fundamentally flawed? (wouldn't be the first time)

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/amaitland/Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge there is a WebView2 example demonstrating taking browser requests and fulfilling them directly with asp net core. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge/

Comment: @amaitland,  that "worked a treat," as they say.  I still have some more work in terms of 1) having the WPF wrapper in a different assembly, and 2) getting angular to actually work in deployment.  But, in terms of the question asked,  this was exactly what i needed.  What a great library!

Comment: Great! If there are additional examples you'd like to add then a pull request would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge](https://github.com/amaitland/Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge) offers a solution to the problem.  It uses owin to host the server-side code in memory, and provides a RequestInterceptor to cleanly relay all requests to the "server" code.

The link above has working examples, but briefly:

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
private IWebHost _host;
private AppFunc _appFunc;

public AppFunc AppFunc
{
    get { return _appFunc; }
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");

    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
      {
          var builder = new WebHostBuilder();

          builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
          {
              var server = new OwinServer();
              server.UseOwin(appFunc =>
              {
                  _appFunc = appFunc;
              });

              services.AddSingleton<IServer>(server);
          });

          _host = builder
              .UseStartup<Startup>()
              .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .Build();

          await _host.RunAsync();
      });            
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private AppFunc _appFunc;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Browser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += Browser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
}

private void Browser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSuccess)
    {
        _appFunc = ((App)Application.Current).AppFunc;
        Browser.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += BrowserWebResourceRequestedAsync;
        Browser.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
    }
}

private async void BrowserWebResourceRequestedAsync(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.GetDeferral();

    var request = new ResourceRequest(e.Request.Uri, e.Request.Method, e.Request.Headers, e.Request.Content);

    var response = await RequestInterceptor.ProcessRequest(_appFunc, request);

    var coreWebView2 = (CoreWebView2)sender;

    e.Response = coreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceResponse(response.Stream, response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase, response.GetHeaderString());

    deferral.Complete();
}
```